# where to put config for turnip step definitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to build testing capability for my rails application. I am using turnip to write feature test. In the github page, it is said that after putting the step definitions in a module "You can now include this module in RSpec". But it is not clear where the referred `RSpec` is. Is it a folder or a file and where it is?

Could anyone please clarify on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RSpec.configure` block mentioned in the turnip documentation can be found in `spec/spec_helper.rb` and/or `spec/rails_helper.rb`. It is possible that you have only one of the files. There, you can include your steps:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include MonsterSteps

  # other settings...
end
```

The difference between the two is that the former loads only a minimal amount of code to make library specs faster, and the latter one loads the entire Rails stack. You need to decide on your own where you need the helpers. If you are not sure, put it in `spec/spec_helper.rb` as this will make it available to all specs.

If you don't have a `rspec` folder at all, you need to add `rspec-rails` to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rspec-rails', group: [:development, :test]
```

then run

```
bundle install
```

and finally generate the basic RSpec files with

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

Comment: I have another question. How about the `turnip_helper`. I created a file with this name inside spec folder and put 'Dir.glob("spec/support/*steps.rb") { |f| load f, true }' to tell it the path to step definitions, but it did not work; I mean when running `spec/acceptance/home_page_links.feature`, it gives an error that it can not recognize the step.

Comment: Sorry but you should post another question for that, including the relevant files. Post a link here and I will take a look at it.

Comment: I posted it here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494204/how-to-create-and-configure-turnip-helper